# Numpy get secondary diagonal with offset=1 and change the values

Tags: python, numpy

I have this 6x6 matrix filled with 0s. I got the secondary diagonal in `sec_diag`. The thing I am trying to do is to change the values of above the `sec_diag` inside the matrix with the odds numbers from 9-1 `[9,7,5,3,1]`

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((6,6), int)
sec_diag = np.diagonal(np.fliplr(x), offset=1)
```

The result should look like this:

```
[[0,0,0,0,9,0],
 [0,0,0,7,0,0],
 [0,0,5,0,0,0],
 [0,3,0,0,0,0],
 [1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

EDIT: `np.fill_diagonal` isn't going to work.

Comment: Your expected result is a 5x6 array? And the 5 was omitted?

Comment: btw.: `np.fill_diagonal(np.fliplr(x[:-1,:-1]), [9,7,5,3,1])` works just fine.

Comment: No I just forgot to mention the 5 sorry... Edited it now

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @MichaelSzczesny it works... much appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use roll

```py
x = np.zeros((6,6),dtype=np.int32)
np.fill_diagonal(np.fliplr(x), [9,7,5,3,1,0])
xr = np.roll(x,-1,axis=1)
print(xr)
```

**Output**

```sh
[[0 0 0 0 9 0]
 [0 0 0 7 0 0]
 [0 0 5 0 0 0]
 [0 3 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try with a double loop